# Issue with string attribute in directive

Tags: angular

I have an issue with attribute directive.

I have defined following directive:

```ts
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[chooseMe]'
})

export class ChooseMe {
    @Input('chooseMe') data: string;
    constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log(this.data);    
}
}
```

And I hook it like that:

```ts
<button [chooseMe]="example"> W/E</button>
```

And of course, in my component I have:

```ts
@Component({
...,
directives:[ChooseMe]
})
```

However, each time `this.data` is undefined. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Inputs are not set before `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time.
`ngOnInit()` is called after the first `ngOnChanges()`:

```ts
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[chooseMe]'
})
export class ChooseMe {
    @Input('chooseMe') data: string;
    constructor(private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.data);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Gunter is correct -  just check it with your code - http://plnkr.co/edit/UoE1mIvfympVxPe6rNtd?p=preview

Comment: Maybe `example` is still `undefined`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, you are right - I want to pass plain string. is it possible?

Comment: `[chooseMe]="'example'"` or `chooseMe="example"`

Comment: Thanks @micronyks for fixing the typo and the Plunker :)